# How to select two columns from multiple tables and put them next to each other (no relationships or critera) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need a SQL statement that will allow me to take one column from one table, one column from another table, and present them side-by-side.  I've been poring through the literature on JOINs but they always seem to require an "on" clause which I'm not interested in.

The closest thing I've found is a "NATURAL JOIN", but that seems to output a result that gives me all the rows from column 2 for each row from column 1.  Any ideas?

Just for illustrative purposes, this is what I want...

```
Table 1

t11
---
 0
---
 1
---
 2

Table 2

t21
---
 a
---
 b
---
 c
```

Desired result:

```
Table 3 (or output of MySQL statement)

t31 | t32
--- | ---
 0  |  a
--- | ---
 1  |  b
--- | ---
 2  |  c
```

Comment: What if the two tables differ in number of rows? And in which order the rows from those two tables are based on?

Comment: You can be guaranteed that they don't differ in the number of rows.  I don't care about the order at the moment.  Just want the data from each column

Comment: Mind explaining why you need this if they don't relate and order doesn't matter?

Comment: Because I'm working on a problem and it's what I'd like to accomplish?  Did you downvote my question?

Comment: I think what @Sami means is that if there is no obvious relationship between each table, then it is difficult to tell the database how to pair them. In general, when selecting from a relational database, there is no guaranteed row order. Is it possible that you could give each table a primary key, so there is a 1:1 relationship between them?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote. Just curious why two separate selects isn't suitable and what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
    T1.a AS from_Table1,
    T2.a AS from_Table2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a,
            @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
        FROM t11, (SELECT @rn1 := 0) var
    ) AS T1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            a,
            @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
        FROM t21, (SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
    ) AS T2 
ON T1.row_number = T2.row_number;
```

---

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aab67/1/0)

---

**Explanation:**

I've used mysql user defined variables in this query.

In order to understand the above query you need to run this query alone.

```
SELECT
    a,
    @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
FROM t11, (SELECT @rn1 := 0) var;
```

This query will give the following output:

**From Table t11:**

```
a   row_number

0      1
1      2
2      3
```

Look I've created a temporary table with data from table `t11` and assigned each row a number i.e. a row number (by the mysql user defined variable `@rn1`).

Look, `(SELECT @rn1 := 0) var` this line in the query is the initialization part. I mean it's initialized once with value `zero`. Later in every look up of the table `t11` the variable `@rn1` is incremented by `1` and printed along with the column `a` in the corresponding row.

In the same way I've created another temporary table with data from `t21` and did the same as above.

```
SELECT
    a,
    @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
FROM t21, (SELECT @rn2 := 0) var;
```

**From Table t21:**

```
a   row_number

a      1
b      2
c      3
```

Now you have something to make an `INNER JOIN` between these two tables (`i.e. row_number`).

So join these two tables `ON row_number` and get the expected result.

```
from_Table1     from_Table2

0                   a
1                   b 
2                   c
```

**CAUTION:**

Since you don't have any ordering while selecting data from tables you might get random result. I appreciate ordering by some field while selecting from tables.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the `@rn1`/`@rn2` directives?  I'm not familiar with that

Comment: Sure. Wait for couple of minutes. I am preparing my answer to be more effective.

Comment: Okay, so the purpose of creating that "pseudo column" (row_number) is so that the JOIN has something to act on?

Comment: Hmm, okay, so it's still relatively complicated then to just grab columns.  Any insight into why that is (just wondering if you happen to know)?

Comment: You need something to make a relationship between two tables where there's no such relationship between them. That's one way you can sometimes make relationship among unrelated tables.

Comment: @Funktr0n: it's easier with some other databases, which have a built-in row numbering function (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()` in Oracle). The alternative, as I mentioned under the question, is to add PKs so you have something to join on.

Comment: 1000111 + halfer: Got it, very much appreciated.  Was trying to solve a problem using an unorthodox method, but it looks like there just isn't much internal support for the approach I had hoped to take.  The literature didn't really explicitly count out the idea, but thanks for clearing it up (and offering a solution).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use this query. I think it can help you in getting your desired result.

```
SELECT Column1 , Column2
FROM
(SELECT Column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn FROM Table1) AS table1_new 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT Column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn FROM Table2) AS table2_new
ON table1_new.rn = table2_new.rn;
```

Its an easy query. let me explain what it is actually doing.

We are Selecting **column1** from **table1** and making a column **rn** which represents **row number** for each row of **table1**.

```
(SELECT C1 AS Column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn FROM Table1) AS table1_new
```

Then we are doing the same thing as above for table 2 in the part of the query below.

```
(SELECT C2 AS Column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn FROM Table2) AS table2_new
```

Then we are joining these two tables on the generated **row numbers**.

```
ON table1_new.rn = table2_new.rn;
```

And in the part below we are selecting **Column1** and **Column2** from the joined table.

```
SELECT Column1 , Column2
```

Despite using the on clause we are not disturbing the order of the columns. I hope it answers your question!