# How can I display two columns together in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 queries that return data in the form:

query 1:

```
column 1
a
b
c
```

query 2:

```
column 2
d
e
```

How can I combine the 2 queries to get output as:

```
column 1 column 2
a        d
b        e
c
```

The order of data in the columns does not matter. 
Possibly anything with joins ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select two columns from multiple tables and put them next to each other (no relationships or critera) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116796/how-to-select-two-columns-from-multiple-tables-and-put-them-next-to-each-other)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using 3.21.0

Comment: `SELECT column1, column2 FROM yourtable`?

Comment: @Shawn Columns are a result of queries. Not part of tables.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is selecting both columns with row_number() and join them by the row_number. One must be aware to select first from the table with the higher number of rows. Example:

```
select
    col_1,
    col_2
from (
    select
        a.col_1,
        row_number() over () rn
    from a
) s1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    select
        b.col_2,
        row_number() over () rn
    from b
    ) s2 on s1.rn = s2.rn
```

Comment: Any method without row_number() ? Columns 1 and 2 can have any n, m rows each which cannot be assumed.

Comment: as Zaynul Abadin Tuhin mentioned, use FULL OUTER JOIN instead of OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
  select t1.col1,t2.col2 from 
    (
    select *,row_number() over(order by col1) rn from query1
    ) t1 full outer join
    (
    select *,row_number() over(order by col2) rn from query2
    ) t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn
```

For n,m rows use full outer join

Comment: Any method without row_number() ?

Comment: @newperson23ws any problem with row_number() for n,m rows use full outer join